# How was this derivative simplified?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

1. $${dy \over dx}=-{{1 \over 12} \over {\sqrt{143} \over 12}} \cdot { \pi \over 24 } \cdot \cos{\pi \cdot {2 \over 3} \over 4} $$
2. $${dy \over dx}=-{{\pi \over \sqrt{143}} \cdot {1 \over 24}} \cdot \cos{1 \over 9}\ \pi $$

How was the derivative in #1 simplified to #2. 
The part I am having trouble following is how $\cos{\pi \cdot {2 \over 3} \over 4}$ became $\cos{1 \over 9}\ \pi $. The rest is clear to me.

Thank you!

Comment: it should be $\cos(\pi/6)$.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably just a mistake, $\frac{\pi \frac23}4=\frac{\pi}6$ and $\cos(\pi/6)\approx 0.8660254037844387$ and $\cos(\pi/9)\approx 0.9396926207859084$.

Comment: That is what I am thinking as well. Very frustrating. This is coming straight from WebAssign so normally I wouldn't expect any mistakes.

Comment: @Elmar zander:I guess the second one should be $cos(\pi/9)$

Comment: @user1772257 Of course, I'll change that.

Answer (score 0):

You could evaluate $\cos{\pi / 6}$ & $\cos{\pi / 9}$ using any calculator and verify that the two derivatives are unequal.